# values are not inserted into the database-no warnings or errors

Tags: php, sql, function

The output on the page is fine, no errors or warnings. and it seems it should insert the values into the database but it doesn't.
var_dump($result) result is "boolean false". when I insert query from the command line it works.

the function:

```
    function handlePostForm(){
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST['formSumbit']) && !empty($_POST['newheader']) && !empty($_POST['newpost']))
    {
       $varHeader = $_POST['newheader'];
       $varContent = $_POST['newpost'];
       $varDate = date('Y-m-d'); 
       $order ="INSERT INTO posts (header,content,post_date) VALUES      ('$varHeader','$varContent','$varDate')";
        $result = mysql_query($order);

    }

    else 
    echo "error";
    }
    }
```

apart of the html form with calling to the function:

```
<?php include('post_func.php'); ?>
<title>new post</title>
</head>
    <body dir="rtl">
    <h1>new post</h1>
    <form method='post' action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    header:
    <input type="text" name="newheader" maxlength="100" style="width:500px;">
    post:
    <textarea  <input type="text" name="newpost" maxlength="100" style="width:500px;  height:500px;"/></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="formSumbit" value="sumbit" />
    </form>

    <?php

    handlePostForm();

    ?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error log? What errors do you get? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this? Have you run the query from the command line?

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: What does `var_dump($result)` show? If `FALSE`, `echo mysql_error()`.

Comment: Also, try to debug the actual query; `echo '<pre>' . $order . '</pre>';` check if it contains errors and/or test it inside PhpMyAdmin. But **please** improve your code, it's very dangerous and vulnerable for SQL injection

Comment: var_dump result is "boolean false". when I insert query from the command line it works.

Comment: but I don't get the "error" msg when I fill the form.

Comment: Thank you  MichaelRushton , I solved the issue thanks to you. thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

For getting details error you may try to use connection handler in your mysql_query() function and use mysql_insert_id to get double sure about your insertion. Also make sure that you have use mysql_select_db() function just after mysql_connection to select the database.

Following will be code after applying above thing:

```
 function handlePostForm(){
 global $conn;//YOur connection
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
if(isset($_POST['formSumbit']) && !empty($_POST['newheader']) && !empty($_POST['newpost']))
{
   $varHeader = $_POST['newheader'];
   $varContent = $_POST['newpost'];
   $varDate = date('Y-m-d'); 
   $order ="INSERT INTO posts (header,content,post_date) VALUES      ('$varHeader','$varContent','$varDate')";
    $result = mysql_query($order ,$conn);

}

else 
echo "error";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
mysql_select_db("application", $con);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO    program_info(prog_title,location,count,p_date,p_start,p_end,advisor_name,advisor_email,advisor_phone,stud1_name,stud1_email,stud1_phone,stud2_name,st
ud2_email,stud2_phone,program)
    VALUES ('$_POST[event_title]','$_POST[event_location]','$_POST[estimated_count]','','$_POST[event_starttime]','$_POST[event_endtime]','$_POST[advisor]','$_POST[advisor_email]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[student1]','$_POST[student1_email]','$_POST[studentphone1]','$_POST[student2]','$_POST[student2_email]','$_POST[studentphone2]','$_POST[program])");
    $temp=$_POST['event_date'];
    echo $temp;
}else`
{ echo "error";
}
```